# Is the following proof that $I_n\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$ for all $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Is the following proof to show $I_n \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}$ for all $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ correct? (Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix with $n$-rows)

\begin{align*}
I_n \mathbf{v} & = [\mathbf{e}_1\ \ \mathbf{e}_2\ \ \cdots\ \ \mathbf{e}_n] \mathbf{v} =\ v_1\mathbf{e}_1\ +\ v_2\mathbf{e}_2\ + \cdots +\ v_n\mathbf{e}_n\\
\\ &= [v_1\ 0\ \cdots \ 0]^T + [0\ v_2\ \cdots\ 0]^T \ + \cdots +\ [0\ 0\ \cdots\ v_n]^T\\
\\ & = [v_1\ v_2\ \cdots\ v_n]^T = \mathbf{v}   .
\end{align*}

I feel like the notation is a bit weird and the proof doesn't exactly look very "formal" or "professional". How can I write it better (if possible)?

Comment: I am writing this comment so that you get a notification: First of all, I want to emphasize that it is not **necessary** to do a componentwise proof (i.e. there is nothing wrong with writing out the matrices like you did)  - but it's definitely much quicker. That being said, I have explained how you can improve your proof. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the following proof correct?

I have two remarks regarding the following equation:$$(e_1\cdots e_n)\cdot v =\ v_1e_1\ +\ v_2e_2\ + \cdots +\ v_ne_n$$

- First of all, I would write$$\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\\vdots \\e_n\end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\ v_1e_1+ \cdots +v_ne_n$$instead, since we take the product of $v$ with the rows of $I$, not its columns.
- You are doing two steps at once:$$\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\\vdots \\e_n\end{pmatrix}\cdot v =\ (e_1\cdot v)e_1+ \cdots +(e_n\cdot v)e_n=\ v_1e_1+ \cdots +v_ne_n$$The first step is just the definition of matrix multiplication, but in the second step we use the fact that $e{}_i\cdot v=v{}_i$. This can be proven by induction, see below.

> I feel like the notation is a bit weird and the proof doesn't exactly look very "formal" or "professional". How can I write it better (if possible)?

Indeed, proofs become very bulky if we write out the entire matrices. So it's in our best interest to define all relevant operations on matrices componentwise and to proof the equality of matrices componentwise:

Let $\mathbb{R}^n\ni v\mapsto v_i\in\mathbb{R}$ be the projection to the $i$-th component. Note that $I_n v=v$ is equivalent to $$(I_n v)_i=v_i\quad\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$
And the latter can easily be derived using the componentwise definition of matrix multiplication and the identity matrix:
$$(I_n v)_i=\sum_{j=1}^n(I_n)_{ij}v_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{ij}v_j=v_i$$
In the last step, we have used the following fact:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\forall v\in\mathbb R^n:\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}:e{}_i\cdot v=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{ij}v_j=v_i$$
This can easily be proven using induction.

Comment: I'd say that OP's proof is conponentwise and essentially equivalent to the one in this answer.

Comment: @Leo Proving the equality componentwise means proving that$$(I_n v)_i=v_i$$for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, which as I said implies that $Iv=v$. So the OP's proof is not componentwise. He tried to prove $Iv=v$ by writing out the entire matrices and vectors. Not only is this far less elegant, but the proof is also incomplete, since the equality$$[\mathbf{e}_1\ \ \mathbf{e}_2\ \ \cdots\ \ \mathbf{e}_n] \mathbf{v} =\ v_1\mathbf{e}_1\ +\ v_2\mathbf{e}_2\ + \cdots +\ v_n\mathbf{e}_n\\
\\ $$is unjustified.

Comment: @Filippo The equality you point out is a standard, though often lesser known equality, relating multiplying a matrix on the right by a column vector with a linear combination of its columns. It's "unjustified" like $\sum_j\delta_{ji}v_j=v_i$ is unjustified in your answer (which it is, but it's a standard trick, so there's no problem). Provided the OP has access to this equality, I have no issue with the solution in the question. That said, +1 for giving what the OP asked for: an alternative.

Comment: @TheoBendit You are absolutely right, I have been a hyprocrite - the part that I ommited is precisely the part that the OP ommited: On the one hand, the equation $\sum_j\delta_{ji}v_j=v_i$ that I left unjustified can be rewritten as $\displaystyle{e_i\cdot v=v_i}$. On the other hand, the equation$$\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\\vdots \\e_n\end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\ v_1e_1+ \cdots +v_ne_n$$can be devided into two steps:$$\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\\vdots \\e_n\end{pmatrix}\cdot v =\ (e_1\cdot v)e_1+ \cdots +(e_n\cdot v)e_n=\ v_1e_1+ \cdots +v_ne_n$$

Comment: The first step is just the definition of matrix multiplication and in the second step we use that $\displaystyle{e_i\cdot v=v_i}$. So the proof of the OP was "incomplete" in the exact same way that my proof was incomplete. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Filippo Don't beat yourself up! It's a good answer, and expanding on the OP's equality makes it even better. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit I appreciate that! When I had my linear algebra course, it took me a lot of time to embrace componentwise proofs. But when I did, I even started believing that it's the only "right" thing to do. Your comment made me realize that I was wrong. So I learned something from this discussion - thank you!